# mule,How to trigger a flow in java class

Tags: mule

I had created a java class to catch the systemException(DB connection Fail),
In the class I tried to reconnect to DB for 10 times.
If connect success,I want to restart the normal flow.
So how can I restart the flow in this class??
Any advise?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Add your flow config. Mention where this Class is being called in the flow. Provide more details to get proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stop and start the flows by getting them through the mule registry and invoking the start and stop method respectively. An example of this would be :

```
    Flow myFlow = (Flow) eventContext.getMuleContext().getRegistry().get("FlowName");
    myFlow.stop();
    myFlow.start();
```

But I don't think this is the ideal approach and further more I don't think that this would resolve your issue.

I am under the impression you are using the "old" JDBC connector. This connector has a reconnection policy that would do this for you. please refer to http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Configuring+Reconnection+Strategies for further information.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet is useful when your flow is initially stopped and it's necessary to start it based on some condition

```
<scripting:component>
    <scripting:script engine="groovy">
 app.registry.lookupFlowConstruct('muleflow').start()
       ( or) 
muleContext.registry.lookupFlowConstruct('muleflow').start()
    </scripting:script>
</scripting:component>
```