# Make Mule flow execution configurable in xml

Tags: xml, configuration, mule

We are developing an application that makes use of different flows that are configured in xml.
Now our application is ready to receive all requests, but some requests cannot be executed in a first phase. It would be great if it could be made configurable whether the flows are enabled or not.

I'm looking for an elegant solution to disable some flows in my mule configuration based on a configurable parameter (preferably in the server configuration, other option is our maven configuration).

```
<flow name="basic_tutorialFlow1" doc:name="basic_tutorialFlow1">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="${incoming.dir}" moveToDirectory="${archive.dir}" fileAge="10000" responseTimeout="10000" connector-ref="input"/>
    <logger message="Current payload is #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <set-payload value="#['Hello, ' + payload + '. Today is ' + server.dateTime.format('dd/MM/yy') + '.' ]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
</flow>
```

I've been looking into the flow choice control, but maybe there is something like a enabled/disabled attribute that can be added?

Comment: There is a setting called initialState (stopped / started) but if you have an HTTP input connector, the listener is still active.

`<flow name="basic_tutorialFlow1" doc:name="basic_tutorialFlow1" initialState="started">....</flow>"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make all your flows not to start at server startup with initialState=stopped.

Then you can write one master flow with java component in it that manually starts the flows as you want.

See answer at - [mule,How to trigger a flow in java class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26083519/mule-how-to-trigger-a-flow-in-java-class)